# Intalling Rails in windows activesupport requires Ruby version >= 2.2.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a problem installing rails on my computer.

```
ruby -v 
ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [x64-mingw32]
```

I get this error message :

> ERROR:  Error installing rails:
>           activesupport requires Ruby version >= 2.2.2.

How can I install rails?

Comment: Are You sure You are not using rvm also or rbenv?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the installer

```
http://railsinstaller.org/en
```

For Windows
Make sure all required components are added to your path.
Try using a path editor software or Environment variable editor.